# Como configurar a Sessão?

Tags: php

Tenho essa atividade proposta:

Esta é a Atividade Semanal da terceira competência e na competência foi mostrado o que é e como utilizar funções com argumentos e retornos, escopo de variáveis, formulários, método de envio GET e POST, sessões, a função `isset()`, entre outros comandos importantes no desenvolvimento de um sistema. Agora precisamos verificar se você sabe utilizar o conhecimento exposto.

**Atividade**

Nesta atividade cada aluno deve modificar a aplicação da competência 2. Se você não fez, terá que fazer agora. No entanto, esta nova aplicação irá ter iteração com o usuário através de hiperlinks e um formulário web. Você terá que decidir adequadamente quando for necessário utilizar GET ou POST.

A aplicação deverá mostrar algumas palavras em hiperlink, também, mais abaixo na mesma página, deve mostrar um formulário para enviar uma palavra e no final deverá ter duas tabelas, um com palavras com o total de letras ímpares e a outra com o total de letras pares.

As palavras dos hiperlinks são as mesmas do array da atividade anterior. Quando o usuário clicar em uma delas, irá aparecer na tabela correta. Com o formulário, o usuário poderá enviar mais uma palavra para a tabela.

A palavra que ele quiser. Para esta solução, será avaliado se teve uso de função, sessão, envio e recepção pelo método GET e POST. Abaixo tem o array de palavras e uma figura mostrando o resultado no navegador.

```
$valores = ['estudar', 'educação', 'esforço', 'persistência', 'dedicação', 'crescimento', 'evolução', 'sabedoria', 'trabalho', 'entusiasmo', 'alegria', 'vitoria', 'sucesso', 'profissão', 'conhecimento', 'vida'];
```

Já consegui fazer uma parte, porém na hora de iniciar a sessão para dar um echo nas variáveis selecionadas não consigo fazê-lo corretamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> Atividade Semanal 2 </title>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=estudar">estudar</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=educação">educação</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=esforço">esforço</a>
<a href="teste.php?palavra=persistência">persistência</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=dedicação">dedicação</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=crescimento">crescimento</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=evolução">evolução</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=sabedoria">sabedoria</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=trabalho">trabalho</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=entusiasmo">entusiasmo</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=alegria">alegria</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=vitoria">vitoria</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=sucesso">sucesso</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=profissão">profissão</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=conhecimento">conhecimento</a>
    <a href="teste.php?palavra=vida">vida</a>

            <form action="teste.php" method="post">
<label for="palavra"> Insira a palavra: </label>
<input id="palavra" name="palavra" type="text" name="post" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
</form>

<table width="200" border=" 1">
<tr>
<tr alingn="center"> 
<td align="center">Palavras</td>
<td align="center">Quantidade de Letras </td>
</tr>

<?php

$palavaead = $_POST['palavra'];
echo "<h1>Tabela Par</h1>";
$total = strlen(utf8_decode($palavaead));
if ($total % 2 == 0){ 
echo '<tr align="center"> 
<td align="center">' . $palavaead . '</td>
<td align="center">' . $total . '</td>
</tr>';
}

$palavaead = $_GET['palavra'];
$total = strlen(utf8_decode($palavaead));
if ($total % 2 == 0){ 
echo '<tr align="center"> 
<td align="center">' . $palavaead . '</td>
<td align="center">' . $total . '</td>
</tr>';
}
?>

<table width="200" border=" 1">
<tr>
<tr alingn="center"> 
<td align="center">Palavras</td>
<td align="center">Quantidade de Letras </td>
</tr>

<?php
$palavaead= $_POST['palavra'];
echo "<h1>Tabela Impar</h1>";
$total = strlen(utf8_decode($palavaead));
if ($total % 2 <> 0){ 
echo '<tr align="center"> 
<td align="center">' . $palavaead . '</td>
<td align="center">' . $total . '</td>
</tr>';
}

$palavaead = $_GET['palavra'];
$total = strlen(utf8_decode($palavaead));
if ($total % 2 <> 0){ 
echo '<tr align="center"> 
<td align="center">' . $palavaead . '</td>
<td align="center">' . $total . '</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
</html>
```

Gostaria de uma orientação de como iniciar a sessão para armazena as variáveis inseridas pelo POST e GET. Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi exatamente o que você precisa, mas acho que o exemplo abaixo pode te ajudar.

```
<?php
// inicia a seção. antes de escrever qualquer html na página
session_start();


// DEFINE O CHARSET COMO UTF-8
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

// se session['palavras'] não iniciada, inicia com valores da atividade anterior
if (!isset($_SESSION['palavras'])) {
    // array da atividade anterior com as palavras
    $valores = ['estudar', 'educação', 'esforço', 'persistência', 'dedicação', 'crescimento', 'evolução', 'sabedoria', 'trabalho', 'entusiasmo', 'alegria', 'vitoria', 'sucesso', 'profissão', 'conhecimento', 'vida'];
    $_SESSION['palavras'] = $valores;
}



// se recebeu POST
if (isset($_POST['palavra'])) { // se recebeu post
    // adiciona uma nova palavra à session
    $_SESSION['palavras'][] = $_POST['palavra'];
    $post_recebido = $_POST['palavra'];
} else {
    $post_recebido = 'nenhum';
}


// se recebeu GET
if (isset($_GET['palavra'])) { // se recebeu post
    $get_recebido = $_GET['palavra'];
} else {
    $get_recebido = 'nenhum';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> Atividade Semanal 2 </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Palavras existentes:</h1>
<?php
echo count($_SESSION['palavras']) . ' palavras.';


$total_letras = 0;
$array_par = array();
$array_impar = array();

echo '<ul>';
// faz um loop em $_SESSION['palavras']
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['palavras']); $i++) {
    // lista cada palavra em um LI
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="teste.php?palavra=' . $_SESSION['palavras'][$i] . '">' . $_SESSION['palavras'][$i] . '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
    // conta letras
    $total_letras += mb_strlen($_SESSION['palavras'][$i], 'UTF-8'); // contar corretamente considerando a codificação utilizada

    // separa pares e ímpares
    $qtd_letras = mb_strlen($_SESSION['palavras'][$i], 'UTF-8');
    if($qtd_letras %2 === 0){
        $array_par[] = $_SESSION['palavras'][$i];
    }else{
        $array_impar[] = $_SESSION['palavras'][$i];
    }


}
echo '</ul>';

$quantidade_de_palavras = count($_SESSION['palavras']);
?>

        <form action="teste.php" method="post">
            <label for="palavra"> Insira a palavra: </label>
            <input id="palavra" name="palavra" type="text" name="post" required><br>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
        </form>



        <table width="200" border=" 1">
            <tr alingn="center"> 
                <td align="center">Palavras</td>
                <td align="center">Quantidade de Letras </td>
                <td align="center">POST recebido</td>
                <td align="center">GET recebido</td>
            </tr>
            <tr alingn="center"> 
                <td align="center"><?php echo $quantidade_de_palavras; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $total_letras; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $post_recebido; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $get_recebido; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <?php

        echo '<strong>PAR</strong>';
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Palavra</td><td>Letras</td></tr>';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array_par); $i++){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $array_par[$i] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mb_strlen($array_par[$i], 'UTF-8') . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br/>';


        echo '<strong>ÍMPAR</strong>';
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Palavra</td><td>Letras</td></tr>';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array_impar); $i++){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $array_impar[$i] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mb_strlen($array_impar[$i], 'UTF-8') . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br/>'


        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Resultado:**

**PAR**
Palavra/Letras
educação/8
persistência/12
evolução/8
trabalho/8 
entusiasmo/10
conhecimento/12
vida/4

**ÍMPAR**
Palavra/Letras
estudar/7
esforço/7
dedicação/9
crescimento/11 
sabedoria/9
alegria/7
vitoria/7
sucesso/7
profissão/9

Qualquer dúvida, posta um comentário.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda, porem preciso que as palavras fiquem em tuas tabelas separadas salvas lá (por meio de uma sessão) como consta na foto, ao clicar em uma palavra ela vá para uma tabela, classificando-a como par ou impar.

Comment: os metodos de entrada devem ser por post ou get(hyperlink)

Comment: devem contar o numero de palavras individualmente e não como um todo.

Comment: Separar se for par ou impar... mas se QUEM for par ou impar? A ordem da palavra na lista? Como assim contar as palavras individualmente?

Comment: Veja, preciso arrumar este codigo que enviei para que separa as palavras obtidas pelo get e post em duas tabelas, uma par outra impar (sera determinado pela quantidade de letras) e assim registrando na sessão. Ex:   insiro palavra "sol" vai ser armazenada na sessão depois o codigo vai pegar todas as palavras da sessão e contar o numero de letras e enviar para uma tabela. só isso.

Comment: eu não consigo fazer a parte da sessão para pegar as strings uma por uma e por no strlen e classificar if palavra % == 2  par  else % <> 2 end if        Tenho de entregar hoje, estou enlouquecendo pois não tenho ajuda dos professores

Comment: Ok, fiz a atualização a partir do seu comentário... veja agora se está como você precisa. Qualquer coisa só avisar.

Comment: @0V3RL04D3R  me avisa se funcionou ou não ok?

Comment: Funcionou agora estou tentando configurar a codificação. http://prntscr.com/c1c49x. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Tudo pronto, Estou imensamente grato.

Comment: Precisando é só mandar msg

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que vc deva pensar da seguinte forma,

1º Pensar que tem que Pegar a palavra por $_GET usando o hiperlink `<a href="pag.php?variavel=estudar">` será enviado a uma variavel na 2 página `$var = $_GET['variavel']`

2º Pegar por `$_POST` uma palavra qualquer digita no `input` (QUE SE CHAMA PALAVRA POR EX) e armazenar ela em uma variavel tbm na segunda página `$palavra = $_POST ['palavra'];`

3º saber que deve usar `$_SESSIONS` para armazenar as palavras enviadas por hiperlink ou pelo campo de input, e testar se ela será par ou impar.

4º Nesse teste, vc só testa e armazena os valores;

5º Vc deve novamente contar o total de letras que tem em cada palavra e armazena em outra variavel... depois disso pede pra escrever em tabelas os resultados

Em sumula,

1- recupera valores
2- TESTA esses valores E ARMAZENA em sessions
3- TESTA esses valores E ESCREVE em tabelas (as sessions armazenadas);